# Foundation 6's Off-canvas not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, off-canvas-menu

I'm trying to get Foundation 6's Off-canvas feature to work. At this point, I am now trying to get Zurb's own example out of their documentation (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#complete-example) to work.

When my button to open the canvas is clicked, nothing happens. No sliding, no fading, nothing.

I have checked that `foundation.js` is being included in the page. I can see that the event handler is bound to the button.

Ideas? Thanks in advance!

HTML source:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home | LearnLojban</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:700,700i|Pangolin|Signika&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>
      <!-- Close button -->
      <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>

      <!-- Menu -->
      <ul class="vertical menu">
        <li><a href="#">Foundation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dot</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ZURB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Com</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Slash</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvas">Open Menu</button>
    </div>

    <script src="static/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your HTML, even if it is the example from the documentation

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, done. HTML added.

Comment: See my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the off-canvas isn't working is because you are not initializing the Foundation JS.

In either a jQuery `.ready()` or after `<script>` elements of your `index.html` you need to call `$(document).foundation();` per the [installation documentation example](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html#html-starter-template)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

OR:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4n7L1d3n/1/) with the basic off-canvas example with `$(document).foundation()` being called and the functionality working using `ready()`.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4n7L1d3n/2/) without `$(document).foundation()` being called and you'll immediately see that the functionality is failing.

Call `$(document).foundation()` after all the scripts have loaded and you should be able to get off-canvas and any other functionality up and running.

You can also target specific elements by calling `foundation()` on that element.

```
$('#foo').foundation(); // initialize all plugins within the element `#foo`
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4n7L1d3n/3/) demonstrating targeting a specific element.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That was it. Thanks! I would not have thought to review the installation documentation.

Answer (score -1):

So, I've been trying to implement the off canvas navigation for a few weeks now. I've finally figured out a solution.

Turns out that none of the js files that were provided triggered the off canvas menu, so I decided to use Foundation's JS files on their documentation site (since their off canvas worked perfectly for them).

These are the three scripts I used:

```
<script src="http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/assets/js/vendor.js?hash=eceb3a0cb6a9a3f95854c532a6ebbd81"></script>

<script src="http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/assets/js/foundation.js?hash=b679e2177e3de7e04f4c100d03af1ad3"></script>

<script src="http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/assets/js/docs.js?hash=9adc0ae1222c4567178bb0cc7f704ec5"></script>
```

Hope this helps!